# What can the JavaScript prototype system do beyond mimicking a classical class system?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

The prototype system looks much more flexible than the traditional class system, but people seem to feel content with the so-called "best practices", which mimic the traditional class system:

```
function foo() {
  // define instance properties here
}

foo.prototype.method = //define instance method here

new foo()
```

There must be other things that a prototypal system can do with all the flexibility.

Are there uses for a prototypal system outside of mimicking classes? What kinds of things can prototypes do which classes cannot, or are there none?

Comment: related if not duplicate: [Does some JavaScript library use dynamic aspects of the prototype system?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10609822/1048572)

Comment: I'm guessing its much easier to dynamically add methods and such using prototypes, you can extend your "class" very easily.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that a classical class system can also trivially mimic prototypical inheritance.

Answer (score 46):

The prototype system offers a captivating model of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), by implementing inheritance via standard objects. Of course, this is mostly used to express the established and simple concept of classes of instances, but without classes as language-level immutable structures that need specific syntax to create them. By using plain objects, all you can do to objects (and you can do everything) you can now do to "classes" - this is the flexibility you talk of.

This flexibility is then used a lot to extend and alter classes programmatically, using only the given object-mutation capabilities of JavaScript:

- mixins and traits for multiple inheritance
- prototypes can be modified after objects that inherit from them have been instantiated
- higher-order functions and method decorators can be used easily in the creation of prototypes

---

Of course, the prototype model itself is more powerful than to just implement classes. These features are used rather seldom, as the class concept is very useful and widespread, so the actual powers of prototype inheritance are not well-known (and not well-optimised in JS engines :-/)

- switching out prototypes of existing objects can be used to alter their behaviour dramatically. (full support coming with [ES6 `Reflect.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-reflect.setprototypeof))
- a few software engineering patterns can be implemented directly with objects. Examples are the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) with properties, a [chain of responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) including dynamic chains, oh, and of course the [prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

  A good example for the last one would be option objects with defaults. Everyone creates them using

  ```
    var myOptions = extend({}, defaultOptions, optionArgument);
  ```

  but a more dynamic approach would be to use

  ```
    var myOptions = extend(Object.create(defaultOptions), optionArgument);
  ```

Comment: Is there any advantage extending `myOptions` using the more dynamic approach? I mean, usually a configuration object remains identical throughout a function call.

Comment: @Kay: It would be smaller (less memory) and should be created faster, especially with large default objects. Also, changes to the defaults would automatically propagate

Answer (score 31):

Back in June 2013 I answered a question on the [benefits of prototypal inheritance over classical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800964/783743). Since then, I spent a lot of time pondering over inheritance, both prototypal and classical and I wrote extensively about the [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640910/783743)[-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885328/783743) [isomorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27822158/783743).

Yes, the primary use of prototypal inheritance is to simulate classes. However, it can be used for a lot more than to just simulate classes. For example, prototype chains are very similar to scope chains.

## Prototype-Scope Isomorphism as well

Prototypes and scopes in JavaScript have a lot in common. There are three common types of chains in JavaScript:

1. Prototype chains.

   ```
   var foo = {};
   var bar = Object.create(foo);
   var baz = Object.create(bar);

   // chain: baz -> bar -> foo -> Object.prototype -> null
   ```
2. Scope chains.

   ```
   function foo() {
       function bar() {
           function baz() {
               // chain: baz -> bar -> foo -> global
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Method chains.

   ```
   var chain = {
       foo: function () {
           return this;
       },
       bar: function () {
           return this;
       },
       baz: function () {
           return this;
       }
   };

   chain.foo().bar().baz();
   ```

Out of the three, prototype chains and scope chains are the most similar. In fact, you can attach a prototype chain to a scope chain using the [notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61552/783743) [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement.

```
function foo() {
    var bar = {};
    var baz = Object.create(bar);

    with (baz) {
        // chain: baz -> bar -> Object.prototype -> foo -> global
    }
}
```

So what's the use of the prototype-scope isomorphism? One direct use is to model scopes chains using prototype chains. This is exactly what I did for my own programming language [Bianca](https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca), which I implemented in JavaScript.

I first defined the global scope of Bianca, populating it with a bunch of useful math functions in a file aptly named [global.js](https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca/blob/master/lib/global.js) as follows:

```
var global = module.exports = Object.create(null);

global.abs   = new Native(Math.abs);
global.acos  = new Native(Math.acos);
global.asin  = new Native(Math.asin);
global.atan  = new Native(Math.atan);
global.ceil  = new Native(Math.ceil);
global.cos   = new Native(Math.cos);
global.exp   = new Native(Math.exp);
global.floor = new Native(Math.floor);
global.log   = new Native(Math.log);
global.max   = new Native(Math.max);
global.min   = new Native(Math.min);
global.pow   = new Native(Math.pow);
global.round = new Native(Math.round);
global.sin   = new Native(Math.sin);
global.sqrt  = new Native(Math.sqrt);
global.tan   = new Native(Math.tan);

global.max.rest = { type: "number" };
global.min.rest = { type: "number" };

global.sizeof = {
    result: { type: "number" },
    type: "function",
    funct: sizeof,
    params: [{
        type: "array",
        dimensions: []
    }]
};

function Native(funct) {
    this.funct = funct;
    this.type = "function";
    var length = funct.length;
    var params = this.params = [];
    this.result = { type: "number" };
    while (length--) params.push({ type: "number" });
}

function sizeof(array) {
    return array.length;
}
```

Note that I created the global scope using `Object.create(null)`. I did this because the global scope doesn't have any parent scope.

After that, for each program I created a separate program scope which holds the top-level definitions of the program. The code is stored in a file named [analyzer.js](https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca/blob/master/lib/analyzer.js) which is too big to fit into one answer. Here are the first three lines of the file:

```
var parse = require("./ast");
var global = require("./global");
var program = Object.create(global);
```

As you can see, the global scope is the parent of the program scope. Hence, `program` inherits from `global`, making scope variable lookup as simple as an object property lookup. This makes the runtime of the language much simpler.

The program scope contains the top-level definitions of the program. For example, consider the following matrix multiplication program which is stored in the [matrix.bianca](https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca/blob/master/examples/matrix.bianca) file:

```
col(a[3][3], b[3][3], i, j)
    if (j >= 3) a
    a[i][j] += b[i][j]
    col(a, b, i, j + 1)

row(a[3][3], b[3][3], i)
    if (i >= 3) a
    a = col(a, b, i, 0)
    row(a, b, i + 1)

add(a[3][3], b[3][3])
    row(a, b, 0)
```

The top-level definitions are `col`, `row` and `add`. Each of these functions has it's own function scope as well which inherits from the program scope. The code for that can be found on [line 67 of analyzer.js](https://github.com/aaditmshah/bianca/blob/master/lib/analyzer.js#L67):

```
scope = Object.create(program);
```

For example, the function scope of `add` has the definitions for the matrices `a` and `b`.

Hence, beside classes prototypes are also useful for modeling function scopes.

## Prototypes for modeling algebraic data types

Classes are not the only type of abstraction available. In functional programming languages data is modeled using [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

The best example of an algebraic data type is that of a list:

```hs
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

This data definition simply means that a list of a's may either be an empty list (i.e. `Nil`) or else a value of type “a” inserted into a list of a's (i.e. `Cons a (List a)`). For example, the following are all lists:

```hs
Nil                          :: List a
Cons 1 Nil                   :: List Number
Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)          :: List Number
Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)) :: List Number
```

The type variable `a` in the data definition enables [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) (i.e. it allows the list to hold any type of value). For example, `Nil` could be specialized to a list of numbers or a list of booleans because it has the type `List a` where `a` could be anything.

This allows us to create parametric functions like `length`:

```hs
length :: List a -> Number
length Nil        = 0
length (Cons _ l) = 1 + length l
```

The `length` function could be used to find the length of any list irrespective of the type of values it contains because the `length` function simply doesn't care about the values of the list.

In addition to parametric polymorphism most functional programming languages also have some form of [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism). In ad-hoc polymorphism, one specific implementation of a function is chosen depending upon the type of a polymorphic variable.

For example, the `+` operator in JavaScript is used for both addition and string concatenation depending upon the type of the argument. This is a form of ad-hoc polymorphism.

Similarly, in functional programming languages the `map` function is usually overloaded. For example, you may have a different implementation of `map` for lists, a different implementation for sets, etc. Type classes are one way to implement ad-hoc polymorphism. For example, the [`Functor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) type class provides the `map` function:

```hs
class Functor f where
    map :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

We then create specific instances of `Functor` for different data types:

```hs
instance Functor List where
    map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
    map _ Nil        = Nil
    map f (Cons a l) = Cons (f a) (map f l)
```

Prototypes in JavaScript allow us to model both algebraic data types and ad-hoc polymorphism. For example, the above code can be translated one-to-one to JavaScript as follows:

```js
var list = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)));

alert("length: " + length(list));

function square(n) {
    return n * n;
}

var result = list.map(square);

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script>
// data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

function List(constructor) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "constructor", {
        value: constructor || this
    });
}

var Nil = new List;

function Cons(head, tail) {
    var cons  = new List(Cons);
    cons.head = head;
    cons.tail = tail;
    return cons;
}

// parametric polymorphism

function length(a) {
    switch (a.constructor) {
    case Nil:  return 0;
    case Cons: return 1 + length(a.tail);
    }
}

// ad-hoc polymorphism

List.prototype.map = function (f) {
    switch (this.constructor) {
    case Nil:  return Nil;
    case Cons: return Cons(f(this.head), this.tail.map(f));
    }
};
</script>
```

Although classes can be used to model ad-hoc polymorphism as well, all the overloaded functions need to defined in one place. With prototypes, you can define them wherever you want.

## Conclusion

As you can see, prototypes are very versatile. Yes, they are primarily used to model classes. However, they can be used for so many other things.

Some of the other things that prototypes can be used for:

1. Creating [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) with structural sharing.

   - [Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors, pt. 1](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1)
   - [Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors, pt. 2](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-2)
   - [Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors, pt. 3](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-3)

   The basic idea of structural sharing is that instead of modifying an object, create a new object which inherits from the original object and make any modifications you want. Prototypal inheritance excels at that.
2. As others have mentioned, prototypes are dynamic. Hence, you can retroactively add new prototype methods and they will be automatically available on all the instances of the prototype.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A (too) long but entertaining read :-) However, by explaining the prototype-class-isomorphism it misses the point of the question imo - the OP already knows how those work, he wants to know what is beyond that. The only features you mention is that prototypes can be used to implement a scope chain (very interesting example), and that they allow to add methods wherever you want (which seems to be necessary for implementing ADTs).

Comment: Going to read the articles on persistent data structures now. I wonder how prototypes can be used to implement them without leaking old data.

Comment: You're correct. I'll cut down on the length of the answer by removing the prototype-class isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, thank you! However I have read those articles on persistent vectors now, and I don't think prototypes have anything to do with that. Structural sharing does not mean that the objects inherit from each other. Can you give (a link to) an example implementation?

Answer (score 11):

I think that the prototypal inheritance system allows for a much more dynamic addition of methods/properties.

You can easily extend classes written by other people, example being all of the jQuery plugins out there, and you can also easily add to the native classes, add utility functions to strings, arrays and, well, anything.

Example:

```
// I can just add whatever I want to anything I want, whenever I want
String.prototype.first = function(){ return this[0]; };

'Hello'.first() // == 'H'
```

You can also copy methods from other classes,

```
function myString(){
  this[0] = '42';
}
myString.prototype = String.prototype;

foo = new myString();
foo.first() // == '42'
```

It also means you can extend a prototype *after* an object has inherited from it, but those changes will be applied.

And, personally, I find prototypes to be really convenient and simple, laying methods out within an object is really appealing to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there is no such concept of Class. Here everything is object. And all objects in JavaScript are decedent from [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). The prototype property helps in inheritance, When we are developing application in object oriented way. There are more features in prototype, than Class in traditional object oriented structure.

In prototype, you can add properties to function which is written by someone else.

For ex.

```
Array.prototype.print=function(){
  console.log(this);
}
```

**Use in Inheritance:**

You can use inheritance by by using prototype property. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) is how you can use inheritance with JavaScript.

In traditional Class system, you can't modify once the class is defined. But in you can do in JavaScript with prototype system.