# Delegation VS Concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, concatenation, delegation

Javascript lacks a class construct, however you can still achieve inheritance many different ways.

You can mimic classes by utilizing prototypes to create constructor functions and thus implementing inheritance via delegation.

The most common way to do this is with the `new` keyword, but you can also implement `object.create()`.

Alternatively, you can take a concatenative approach and copy behavior that you want your object to inherit directly into the object itself, rather than by pointing its `[[prototype]]` to another object.

What are the advantages and drawbacks of each pattern in JS?

It seems many experts are advocating the concatenative approach, like Doug Crockford for example. The delegation pattern is clearly more popular at the moment, however.

I know that, in general, the concatenative approach is going to be more flexible, but will consume more memory because your copying methods all over the place rather than just referencing a common set.

However, I also know that the V8 engine has ways of optimizing this stuff.

Besides performance, is there anything that you can achieve via delegation that you can achieve via concatenation? For example, in delegation, I can have a method in a super class that implements some basic functionality and in my subclass methods I can call the super's method and then do some subclass-specific computations before returning the final result. I can't think of a way to do this with the concatenative approach without just using a different method name.

Comment: Responding to your first two sentences...  One only starts to understand prototype inheritance when you stop trying to make it "mimic" classes in other languages and start understanding it by itself for what it does and how it works.  I would say I stunted my Javascript learning pace by trying to write Javascript that looked like C++ for far too long rather than just learning how is the best way to do things in Javascript.

Comment: Delegation is better suited for extensibility. Think about plugins (`$.fn === $.prototype`).

Comment: The limitation of the concatenation approach is that the objects cannot  be enhanced after creation (unless you do it manually for every single one of them).

Comment: Multiple inheritance in JS can only be done via concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences are object size and flexibility. Inheriting properties instead of copying them will lead to smaller objects, especially if your method API is relatively large. Also, inheriting properties from a single object that can still be manipulated is much more dynamic (see [Does some JavaScript library use dynamic aspects of the prototype system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10609822/1048572)). It might be more complicated to optimize than inheriting from static objects, but it is still faster than not sharing between objects.

Comment: The look-ups themselves would be slower when using delegation, correct, since you have to walk the prototype chain (at lease once, even if you cache them) for each variable you use in each instance that uses it.

Comment: @LukeP: I actually meant that they would be faster, because method calls can be inlined when they all point to the same function and it's easily derivable that they do on every instance (because all instances inherit it). See how V8 optimises classes. If the methods were placed directly on the instances, you might be able to do the same optimisation once you derived that on every object the property holds the same value, but *that* is more complicated (and IIRC not done in V8)