# Why is the result not what I expect?

Tags: javascript

I'm copying this code snippet into Chrome's console.

```js
function F() {};
F.prototype.fMethod = function WOT() {console.log(this)};

function G() {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(G.prototype, {...F.prototype.fMethod, ...Object.prototype})

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(G.prototype));
```

What I expected `Object.getPrototypeOf(G.prototype)` to return was

```js
{
function WOT, //the content/properties of the object `F.prototype.fMethod` points to.
constructor: ... //the content/properties of the object Object.prototype points to. 
hasOwnProperty: ...
isPrototypeOf: ... 
}
```

You can see what I get on Chrome console here:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do `Function.prototype.method = function() {console.log(this)}`? Why are you doing it in a convoluted way?

Comment: You shouldn't be using  `__proto__`! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto

Comment: @slebetman I'm trying to i) first confirm what is meant by single-inheritance (I read that JavaScript does that) and ii) If my understanding on single-inheritance is correct, I'm trying to 'break' it by making `Function.prototype.__proto__` point to an object that contains 2 `Constructor.prototype`s - 1 from `Object` and the other from `F`

Comment: But your code is not using inheritance correctly. Do not use `__proto__` ever. It is not defined in the specs and is not how inheritance works. The way constructor A inherits from constructor B is `A.prototype = new B()`. Your syntax for inheritance is wrong

Comment: @slebetman Code aside would you be able to offer an explanation of what single-inheritance in JavaScript is? Couldn't find a good article

Comment: @slebetman I've added a picture to the bottom of my post showing me using `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. I think if you had a look at it you might be able to help

Comment: https://javascript.info/prototypes and/or https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read#prototypes (which takes a few seconds to load) may be good references for you. You can also "break single inheritance" by favoring concatenation-based inheritance (many-to-many, providing a 'has-a' relationship) over delegation (many-to-one, providing an 'is-a' relationship via the prototype chain). Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629027/delegation-vs-concatenation-in-javascript. Finally, be aware that you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj)` in place of `myObj.__proto__`.

Comment: Sure. That obviously doesn't answer your question directly, but if it's all you needed in order to become unconfuzzled, you can let me know and I can put it into an answer.

Comment: @Cat I've done some reading (including your resources) and still found myself stuck. I've edited the question to make it clearer and would appreciate you having another look

Comment: @tonitone120 I've only just seen this question - and I'm not sure what you were asking originally, but in the revised version, it seems that you misunderstand what object spread notation does. The reason you see an empty object as output is that the two objects you are spreading (a function object with no special properties added, and `Object.prototype`) both have no enumerable properties.

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond. Is this because the second argument of `Object.setPrototypeOf()` only 'counts' own properties? Or is it just how the objects that have non-enumerable properties (sometimes) visually appear in Chrome and in fact the non-enumerable properties are still there? If they were still there I'd expect `Object.getPrototypeOf(I.prototype).length` to return `0` but it doesn't, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: It's just because the spread syntax (the `...`) only gives you the enumerable properties. This isn't an area I'm massively knowledgeable in and I can't give you any definitive reference, but my understanding is that `...obj` iterates over `obj` to (in this case) add its keys and values to the object being defined - but the default behaviour of iterating over an object is to ignore non-enunerable properties.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from it is not clear what you want to achieve, probably the most close we can be to what you want to achieve could be:

```js
function F() {};
F.prototype.fMethod = function WOT() { console.log(this) };

function G() {};

console.log(Object.prototype);

Object.setPrototypeOf(G, { ...F.prototype,
  // since Object.prototype is an empty object, next line is irrelevant
  ...Object.prototype
});

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(G));
```

Once said that I strongly suggest you to clarify which is your target so we can help you to find a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Don't necessarily want to achieve something just want to know why the result I got was different to the result I expected

Comment: It's hard to say why a clearly empty object is different from what you expect without knowing what you expect @tonitone120 . I can say that your result is clearly an empty object because you are merging two empty objects: `...F.prototype.fMethod` (a function accessed as an object results as an empty object) and `...Object.prototype` which is an empty object

Comment: I think you've hit the mark a bit. What (I think) I'm only learning now is objects that have no enumerable properties (asides from `__proto__`?) appear empty. For instance, a slight change to my code (adding `F.prototype.fMethod.color = "red"`) makes this `color` property show up. Is this because the second argument of `Object.setPrototypeOf` only takes 'own' properties?

Comment: No @tonitone120 , it takes the object as is, what in your code cuts out the not enumerable properties is the object destructuring: `...Object.prototype`

Answer (score 1):

On the line

`Object.setPrototypeOf(G.prototype, {...F.prototype.fMethod, ...Object.prototype})`

You are setting the prototype of `G.prototype` as an empty object because

```js
// You are unpacking two objects
{
  ...F.prototype.fMethod, // is your WOT function which has no owned properties to unpack
  ...Object.prototype // which is an empty object
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroChitolina. So what I'm taking from this is the second argument of Object.setPrototypeOf() only 'counts' own properties?

Comment: Nope, the second argument of `setPrototypeOf` takes the whole object passed. The thing is that you are using the spread operator to unpack a function (which has no enumerable properties) into a new object. The second argument written on your question is the same as `{}`. If you want G to inherit F (with fMethod), you probably have to use `Object.setPrototypeOf(G.prototype, F.prototype)` or declare it as `class G extends F {}`